# Access Control Allow Origin errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, google-chrome, cors

I am learning how to build APIs with Node.js. I was getting cors error when I try to fetch from my browser and my research tells me that, it is difficult to make a request on localhost unless the cors is disabled from the browser so I set up cors but I still kept receiving the error.
Here is my `app.js` and `routes.js` file.

```js
.............
app.use(cors());
app.use("/dashboard", dashboardRouter);
.............
// My routes
router.get("/api/inventory", function (req, res, next) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        if (req.header('Authorization') == 'Bearer test') {
            db.getFullInventory()
                .then(function (result) {
                    resolve(
                        res.json({
                            success: true,
                            data: result
                        }));
                })
                .catch(
                    function (err) {
                        reject(res.json({
                            success: false,
                            data: err
                        }));
                    }
                )
        } else {
            reject(res.json({
                success: false,
                data: "token is invalid"
            }));
        }
    })
});
```

Can someone explain to me, how to make my api compatible. `Postman` works though.

Comment: for time being you can use this https://corsproxy.github.io/

Comment: can you post the exact errors you get .... "CORS errors" is far too vague to help with

Comment: This will sound silly but I set up ```app.use(cors())``` again in ```app.js``` and set ```res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");``` in my routes and it works.
The error was 
```
 Access to fetch at 'x' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Headers is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Comment: hey @sakib11 You can answer your question for others to know.

Comment: Absolutely. I will do that. I am experiencing a routing issue. my ```app.js``` is set to ```var dashboardRouter = require("./routes/dashboard");```
and my router is set to ```router.get('/inventory/:id', function (req, res, next){...})``` and ```router.get("/inventory", function (req, res, next){...}). The routes are exported. When I hit the second one, I get results. When I hit the first one, console says ```GET /dashboard/api/inventory/1233 404```. For some reason it can't find this route. How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an express app.

Please use:

```
npm install cors
```

Then, where you setup your App use:

```
const app = express()
app.use(cors())
```

[See Express CORS Documentation Here](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)

For Modular Routing (which it seems like you're using) you may also need to add CORS to the modular routes.

E.g:

```
router.use(cors())
```

Comment: I have already installed these dependencies. And this is just a snippet.

Comment: Yeah. thank you so much. I have also updated my SNIPPETS again. I visited the express site. If I have set the app to use ```cors```, then if I use routes, shouldn't the routes get to use cors as well?

Answer (score 0):

It may have been a syntax error of some sort.

```js
.............
app.use(cors()); // set this at the beginning of the route usage.
app.use("/dashboard", dashboardRouter);
.............
// My routes
router.get("/api/inventory", function (req, res, next) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // indicating that we will allow any urls
        if (req.header('Authorization') == 'Bearer test') {
            db.getFullInventory()
                .then(function (result) {
                    resolve(
                        res.json({
                            success: true,
                            data: result
                        }));
                })
                .catch(
                    function (err) {
                        reject(res.json({
                            success: false,
                            data: err
                        }));
                    }
                )
        } else {
            reject(res.json({
                success: false,
                data: "token is invalid"
            }));
        }
    })
});
```

Using fetch from browser should look something like this

```js
fetch('http://localhost:3000/dashboard/api/inventory', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer test'
    }
}).then(function (result) {
    return result.json()
}).then(function (value) {
    console.log(value)
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err)
})
```